# Obtain values that match from a nested list in javascript

Tags: javascript, list, ecmascript-6, nested-loops, nested-lists

I'm trying to obtain a list from a list in Javascript.

This is the list:

```js
const cars = [
  {
    id: 1,
    brand: "Mercedes Benz",
    properties: [
    {
      property: "Mechanical",
      value: 2,
    },
    {
      property: "Chemical",
      value: 2,
    },
    {
      property: "Pressure",
      value: 3,
    }],
  },
  
  {
    id: 2,
    brand: "BMW",
    properties: [
    {
      property: "Mechanical",
      value: 5,
    },
    {
      property: "Chemical",
      value: 3,
    },
    {
      property: "Pressure",
      value: 6,
    }],
  }
]
```

**I need the cars which have a determined property with a value greater than X**

For example, if I say that the property is *Mechanical* and the value is *3* I'll obtain the complete object with id 2

Does anyone have an idea? That is having me a hard time

Sorry for the bad formatting of the code, StackOverflow is not letting post it formatted for some reason.

Tip: I paste it on a Node REPL ;)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `filter`:

```js
const desiredProp = "Mechanical";
const minVal = 3;

const filteredCars = cars.filter(car =>
    car.properties.some(
        prop => prop.property === desiredProp && prop.value >= minVal
    )
);
```

If you're only looking for the first match and not an array of all matches, replace `filter` with `find`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `propGreaterThan` function that takes the desired property and the number that you need it to be greater then. Using a combination of `filter` on the `cars` array and `find` on the `properties` array, you can find the appropriate cars.

```js
const cars = [
  {
    id: 1,
    brand: "Mercedes Benz",
    properties: [
    {
      property: "Mechanical",
      value: 2,
    },
    {
      property: "Chemical",
      value: 2,
    },
    {
      property: "Pressure",
      value: 3,
    }],
  },
  
  {
    id: 2,
    brand: "BMW",
    properties: [
    {
      property: "Mechanical",
      value: 5,
    },
    {
      property: "Chemical",
      value: 3,
    },
    {
      property: "Pressure",
      value: 6,
    }],
  }
]

function propGreaterThan(prop, num) {
  return cars.filter(car => {
    return car.properties.find(p => p.property === prop).value > num;
  });
}

console.log(
  propGreaterThan("Chemical", 2)
)
```